# JSON response in Golang’s GIN returning as scrambled data

Tags: json, go, go-gin

I have array of a struct being created from data I collected from the database.

For simplicity, lets say this is the struct:

```
type Person struct {
ID        int    `db:"id, json:"id"`
}

type PessoalController struct{}

func (ctrl PessoalController) GetPessoal(c *gin.Context) { 
    q := "select id from rh"

    rows, err := db.GetDB().Query(q)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var pessoas []Pessoal

    var id
    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&id)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    pessoas = append(pessoas, Pessoal{ ID: id,})

    JsonPessoal, errr := json.Marshal(pessoas)
    if errr != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    c.JSON(200, pessoas)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    return
}
```

When I print it, I do get the JSON I expected. 
But when I send the response, I get raw-looking data like “W3siWQiQjlyNDYslNpYx...”

Have no idea how to proceed.

Edit :  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As is, `err` is never assigned, and we don't know what `c.JSON` is.

Comment: BTW that "raw-looking data" looks like base64-encoded to me. And its first bytes actually decode to `[{"` FWIW…

Comment: Thanks for the input @Marc and kostix,  I've corrected the exemple.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`c.JSON` is serializing into JSON, so you should be doing:

```
c.JSON(200, pessoas)
```

Comment: What is `c.JSON`, after all?

Comment: @kostix In case you really want to know, it's most probably this: https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.JSON.

Comment: @Rafael `c.JSON` makes it easier for data to be respond in JSON. You can still use response writer but you have to manually add the JSON response header and all.

Answer (score 5):

Your codes ans the question itself. Look at it and read my comments in the code.

```
jsonPessoal, errr := json.Marshal(pessoas)
if errr != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%s", jsonPessoal) // still fine here .
// it is fine because you are formating []byte into string using fmt and 
// printing it on console. `%s` makes sures that it echos as string. 

c.JSON(200, jsonPessoal ) // jsonPessoal is still a []byte !! 
if err != nil {
    return
}
```

The correct way to echo json string using gin would be

```
c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{ 
            "code" : http.StatusOK, 
            "message": string(jsonPessoal),// cast it to string before showing
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was curious: Why is that you also return the status in the JSON body if the status is already in the header? Is it just for good practice / convention ?
I'm interested in your answer.

Comment: @RafaelAuyer The header is must but if you return the code in the body, that might help in some cause like for all 200+ request that is all valid but has different use. Like if you are using old Jquery and your response from api returns a 201 then that goes to success call back just like 200. Then you can use the code in the body to show different messge like, Your Resource is Created. Its a personal choice, I use this practise when I design any api. You can skip it if you want.